# HTML table: modify order using mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html-table

I have a MySQL table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Questions` (
  `question_id` INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question` VARCHAR(1024),
  `order` INT
);
```

When displaying the data in an HTML table, the order of the data is sorted by column 'order'. How would one implement incrementing/decrementing order column using some sort of up/down buttons in each table row?

```
...
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $question['question_id'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $question['order'] ?></td>
    <td><button id="up_<?php echo $question['question_id'] ?>">&#x25B2;</button></td>
    <td><button id="down_<?php echo $question['question_id'] ?>">&#x25BC;</button></td>
    <td><?php echo $question['question'] ?></td>
  </tr>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your MySQL query `"(REST OF OLD QUERY HERE) ORDER BY order " . $sort;`

You will need to make links labeled up/down (or something similiar probably) that pass an argument to your script in which way to sort your results.

E.g.: `<a href="index.php?sort=>Ascending</a> <a href="index.php?sort=desc>Descending</a>`

Then, in your PHP script, before the query:

```
$sort = ''; // Default order ascending (auto)
if ( isset ( $_GET [ 'sort' ] ) )
{
   if ( $_GET [ 'sort' ] == 'desc' )
   {
      $sort = 'DESC';
   }
}
```

**Explanation:**

MySQL orders your results ascending by default, so we have to add nothing to the query normally (`$sort='';`). However, if the user clicks the *Descending* link, PHP sets `$sort` to `DESC` and MySQL will order your results descending!

Comment: if your field is actually called `order`, you'll need to include backticks ` around the field as `order`

Comment: hmm, sent that too soon, sorry. `order` is a mysql keyword, the backticks mark it as a field name.

Comment: No problem, I though about adding quotes around it too before.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a manual order, then you will need to add a column to the database to describe that order. Possibly an integer column with a uniqueness constraint (you appear to have that already, sans the constraint).

You can then ORDER BY that column in the SELECT query you issue.

When you want to change the order, you need to swap the values of the rows you want to swap. (You will likely need to set one to a placeholder value, then the other to the old value of the first, then the first to the old value of the second).

This can be achieved with a form for each row containing a hidden input with a row id, and up/down submit buttons. Then in the server side code you can swap row id with row id + 1 or -1 depending on which button was clicked.

You could add JavaScript (and Ajax techniques) to improve the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You could define it in your query in the `ORDER BY` section like:

```
ORDER BY first_order,second_order,second_order`
```

**BUT!**  If you want to have something like buttons on your tables which you can have a dynamic sorting in your tables you could use some **JQUERY plugins** you can refer it here: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery + jQuery UI Sortable instead of a order column. See it here: http://jqueryui.com/sortable

Answer (score -2):

This snippet should to the trick. Any question, throw it to comment.

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx');

if(isset($_GET['q'])){
  $qid = $_GET['q'];
  $act = $_GET['act'];
  $sql = "SELECT `order` FROM test.questions WHERE question_id = '$qid'";
  $rs = mysql_query($sql);
  $r = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
  $order = $r['order'];
  if($act == 'up'){
    if($order == '1') break;
    $up_order = $order - 1;
    $sql = "SELECT question_id FROM test.questions WHERE `order` = '$up_order'";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql);
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    $up_order_id = $r['question_id'];
    $sql = "UPDATE test.questions SET `order` = '$up_order' WHERE question_id = '$qid'";
    mysql_query($sql);
    $sql = "UPDATE test.questions SET `order` = '$order' WHERE question_id = '$up_order_id'";
    mysql_query($sql);
  } else if($act == 'down'){
    $sql = "SELECT MAX(`order`) as `order` FROM test.questions";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql);
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    $max_order = $r['order'];
    if($order == $max_order) break;
    $down_order = $order + 1;
    $sql = "SELECT question_id FROM test.questions WHERE `order` = '$down_order'";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql);
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    $down_order_id = $r['question_id'];
    $sql = "UPDATE test.questions SET `order` = '$down_order' WHERE question_id = '$qid'";
    mysql_query($sql);
    $sql = "UPDATE test.questions SET `order` = '$order' WHERE question_id = '$down_order_id'";
    mysql_query($sql);
  }
  $sql = "";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM test.questions ORDER BY `order`;";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table>";
while(false !== ($r = mysql_fetch_array($rs))){
   echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>$r[question_id]</td>";
      echo "<td>$r[question]</td>";
      echo "<td>$r[order]</td>";
      echo "<td><a href='?q=$r[question_id]&act=up'>UP</a> - <a href='?q=$r[question_id]&act=down'>DOWN</a></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Yes just what David Dorward said. I need a UI to manual order a table and not sorting a column. Thanks anyway

Comment: Yup, I realize the SQL injection issue and several other security issue. But, that's not the question here. from the description: s there a way to make changes in the 'order' using buttons(move-up/down) then update the order in the database?. He/she want to update the field 'order' not HOW TO order his question!.

Comment: @Xin: My answer is not about sorting the column. It's about change the order of the table / question.